# what's the "#define XXX" 's value?

Tags: c++, string

what's the "#define XXX" 's  value?

it has no value but it seems no compile error .normally the define is 
define type replace, but it is define type wiouht replace str.

Comment: There is no value. The XXX is simply considered *defined* by the preprocessor after encountering that declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other have said, its definition is empty, that is, in most contexts its replacement text is empty. However, in the constant expression for a `#if` statement, its value is 0:

```
#define XXX
#if XXX == 0
    // yes, we get here
#elif
    // no, we don't get here
#endif
```

Same thing for a name that is not defined at all:

```
#if YYY == 0
    // yes, we get here
#elif
    // no, we don't get here
#endif
```

The difference between those two is that the latter is not defined, and the former is:

```
#ifdef XXX
    // yes, we get here
#endif

#if defined(XXX)
    // yes, we get here
#endif
```

and for `YYY` neither of those tests succeeds.

Answer (score 11):

It'll replace the replacement text by nothing:

```
#define FOO

int FOO main() FOO
{
}
```

Moreover, `#ifdef FOO` will succeed.

---

Empty defines can be quite useful, for example in this (naive) functional form:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  include <cstdlib>
#  define MakeSureThat(X) if (!(X)) { std::abort(); }
#else
#  define MakeSureThat(X)
#endif
```

Usage:

```
void do_stuff(Foo * p)
{
    MakeSureThat(p != nullptr);       // won't generate any code if NDEBUG
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It will define `XXX` to the **rest of the line**, as usual.

It doesn't matter that it's empty in this case.

There are no any exceptions here.